# Populating labels from Data Browser on Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

At the moment I have a `[PFQuery]` that fetches some labels from the Data Browser on Parse.com. Te query is placed in the `viewDidLoad` method. However, I get a nil value.

The reason for this is that the view is loading the label before Parse fetches its text, resulting on a blank label. 
I found the solution to this, or at least a walk around. If I load the label with a 1 sec. delay, the label can display its title.

This is the code to delay `UILabel`'s load:

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    self.titleLabel.text = fetchedTitleLabel;
});
```

In my opinion I think this is not the best practice. I also thought about placing the query on the AppDelegate, and that works too. But I would like to hear your way of doing this, as I think (in my opinion) this is a common error when fetching data from Parse.com. Thank you!

Comment: The view hierarchy isn't completely laid-out at the instant viewDidLoad is called. You might try moving your query to viewWillAppear. Try that and let me know :)

Comment: @ReidBelton - That is an interesting approach. However, that did not work. Does this work for you?

Comment: Why don't you set the text of the label once the query has returned any results? What you are doing is only working by coincidence, should the request take longer as the time you wait, it will result in the same behavior.

Comment: @BjörnKaiser - I do that, but if the query results arrives later than the load of the label, the label does not receive any text and displays a blank label.

Comment: Can you add the code that fetches the object? This will be of great help.